# can someone explain the steps to compute this equation? Java

Tags: java, equation-solving

Write a program that computes the following equation.
100/1+99/2+98/3+97/4+96/5...3/98+2/99+1/100

I am not asking for a solution. Yes this is a homework problem, but I am not here to copy paste the answers. I asked my professor to explain the problem or how should I approach this problem? She said "I can't tell you anything."

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int i;

    for(i = 100; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        int result = i/j;
        j = j+1;
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it help if I point out that it is really 100/100/100/100.....

Comment: Please edit this question and put the code directly in the question.

Comment: @Takendarkk - That's simply wrong. The common understanding is that division is higher precedence than addition.

Comment: @TedHopp Just slapped myself in the face.

Comment: that´s not an equation

Comment: Is this a test of understanding of order of operations? Some context would help

Comment: what is the initial value of  `j=?`?

Comment: Well, you need to declare and initialise `j`.  You also need to add the fractions together somehow, which you're not doing.

Comment: your `int result` is declared 100 times and getting initialize as well. so put it outside of loop. also put `double or float` instead of `int`

Comment: Also print the result at the end, since it is a result, do you also want to print a temp division result for each iteration (hint).

Comment: i got 383 as my answer. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to observe a "trend" or "pattern" when solving questions of this type.

**Given:** `100/1+99/2+98/3+97/4+96/5...3/98+2/99+1/100`

**We derived:** Numerator/Denominator, let's call it `n` divide by `d` (n/d)

**Pattern Observed:**

- `n - 1` after every loop
- `d + 1` after every loop

So, if you have 100 numbers, you need to loop 100 times. Thus using a for-loop which loops 100 times will seemed appropriate:

```
for(int n=0; n<100; n++) //A loop which loops 100 times from 0 - 100
```

To let n start with 100, we change the loop a little to let n start from 100 instead of 0:

```
for(int n=100; n>0; n--) //A loop which loops 100 times from 100 - 0
```

You settled n, now d needs to start from 1.

```
int d = 1; //declare outside the loop
```

Putting everything together, you get:

```
int d = 1;
double result = 0.0;
for (int n=100; n>0; x--)
{
    result += (double)n/d; //Cast either n or d to double, to prevent loss of precision
    d ++; //add 1 to d after every loop
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. You need to loop like you've done, but then you need to SUM up all the results. In your example you can try:

```
result = result + i/j;
```

or

```
result += i/j;
```

Note that the declaration of result needs to be outside the loop otherwise you are always initializing it.
Also think about the division (hint), you are dividing integers...

Answer (score 0):

if you want the result in the same format then do :

```
int j = 100;
double sum=0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
sum += ((double) j / i);   // typecast as least one of i or j to double.
        System.out.print(j + "/" + i+"+");
  j--;
}

 // here print the sum
```

Comment: @AlvinBunk this is not a complete answer just a hint. see i already comment so many thing.

Comment: i can't put such explanation in comment. Am i right @AlvinBunk

Comment: @Parker it is obeously  `sum` must be initialize with 0;

Comment: @Parker is it oky now

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a [***series***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)).

There is more than one way to define a series, but all things being the same it's more intuitive to have the index of a series increase rather than decrease.

In this case, you could use `i` from 0 to 99.

[image]

Which in java can be:

```
double sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    sum += (100 - i) / (double) (1 + i);
}
```